# Animate multiple lines with plotly that expand frame to frame

Tags: python, animation, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to animate multiple trajectories that expand frame by frame. I managed to do so with `matplotlib`, but now I would like to use `plotly` for better interactivity.

Here is the example with `matplotlib` and how I would like to have it look with plotly as well:

[image: Trajectory plot in matplotlib]

I was able to animate the fractions of the lines of the frame, but not that they expand on the previously plotted lines like in the `matplotlib` example.

```
lines = [[([1, 2], [1, 1]), 
          ([3, 4], [1, 3]), 
          ([8, 7], [4, 3]), 
          ([7, 6], [0, 1])], 
         [([2, 2], [1, 3]), 
          ([4, 3], [3, 3]), 
          ([7, 6], [3, 2]), 
          ([6, 5], [1, 2])], 
         [([2, 1], [3, 3]), 
          ([3, 2], [3, 4]), 
          ([6, 5], [2, 1]), 
          ([5, 6], [2, 3])], 
         [([1, 1], [3, 1]), 
          ([2, 2], [4, 5]), 
          ([5, 4], [1, 0]), 
          ([6, 4], [3, 4])]]

traces=[]
for frame in lines:
    tracesThisFrame = []
    for line in frame:
        tracesThisFrame.append(dict(type='scatter',
                                    x=line[0],
                                    y=line[1]))
    traces.append(tracesThisFrame)

data = traces[0]
frames = []
t = []
for d in traces:
    t = d+t
    frames.append(go.Frame(data=t))

fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=go.Layout(
                                    xaxis=dict(range=[0, 9], autorange=False),
                                    yaxis=dict(range=[0, 6], autorange=False),
                                    title="Start Title",
                                    updatemenus=[dict(
                                        type="buttons",
                                        buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                                                        method="animate",
                                                        args=[None])])]
    ), frames=frames)

pyo.plot(fig)
```